# Android Image animation. Picture reveal from top to bottom

Tags: android, image, animation

I want to display an image, but this image will reveal itself from top to bottom slowly. You can imagine that if this image is a text, then this text will be revealed line by line. And each line is revealed by the fade effect. Is there anyway to do this ? I don't even know which term should I search for.

Comment: Do you mean like diving the image into multiple pieces and then show these pieces one by one from top to bottom ?

Comment: To be exact, imagine a paragraph of text, which means many line. Then the text appear line after line. And yea I want the image reveal itself like that too, except the animation should be smooth. I did think of this method : The image is a 2D matrix of pixels, then I print it out each line of the matrix, at some speed.

Answer (score 1):

There is one way I know to do that and it is just simple and it's by using the class called [TransitionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html).

Here's a simple code you can put on your onCreate and test it.

```
    final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    // Set the initial position of the image
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    final ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new ViewGroup.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            // Use the default transition of TransitionManager
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(layout);

            // Set the final position of the image
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageDetails = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
            imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            imageDetails.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            image.setLayoutParams(imageDetails);

            return true;
        }
    });

    layout.addView(image, imageDetails);
```

There is one disadvantage that I know when using this approach. The minimum SDK version should be 19.

PS: If you want more control on the transitions or animations you make. Just read further on animations and transitions on Android.

Comment: nothing happened when I run. There's a green icon, i tried to touch, but still nothing happened

Comment: try to tap the screen. if you understood the logic on the code you will not be asking this question but just tap the screen. try it and tell me.

Comment: I did tap the screen. Nothing happened.

Comment: did you have a Relative Layout in the activity's view? and set its id to mainLayout? just touch the layout and not the green icon.

Comment: I did. I even set the background color to black for easily monitoring. But nothing happened. I tapped the layout, the icon, outside of the layout, nothing happened.

Comment: make sure your device or emulator has Android 4.4 to support the API 19 minimum requirements. if that doesn't fix it then I do not know what is wrong because it certainly works on my side.

Answer (score 0):

OK, if you want to move the view from top to down, you could just use an animator to animate that. If you want to Reveal the image from top to bottom, then you can do that with a trick. Have an image view and load your image in it. Now have another view on top of it. All you have to is animate the height of that view until, the top coincides with the bottom. You will have your reveal animation.

If you want to create the reveal with fade effect, then you can mask the view on top and animate the mask. I used this in the past to create the circular reveal. For the mask view take a look at this : https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout

Comment: That's short of like that, but not exactly true. When reveal, it should be a fade effect. If you take a paragraph of text, then the whole paragraph is revealed line by line. And each line is revealed, by the fade effect. Something like that